# Update numpy version in spyder

Tags: python, numpy, updates, spyder

I've searched around but I can't seem to find any clear instructions. How can I update the version of Numpy provided in an already installed Spyder environment? I used Anaconda to install Spyder, numpy, Python, everything. I'm running a 32-bit installation on Windows.

Comment: How have you installed Numpy? Are you using Conda, Python(x,y), or any other enviroment, or plain old installer?

Comment: I used Anaconda, which installed everything itself.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait until Continuum updates their repositories. Then, you can use Anaconda to upgrade.

There is the possibility of installing third party build packages from, for example, binstar, but as of today, there is no [Numpy for W32.](https://binstar.org/search?q=platform%3Awin-32+numpy)

If you really need it, you could try to build it yourself. Conda has pretty neat [documentation](http://conda.pydata.org/docs/build.html) on how to do it: you basically need to create a recipe (the building script). I would imagine Numpy is not the easiest package to compile, but maybe you can adapt the recipes for the 64 bits version that are on Binstar.

Comment: I  checked and the current version of Anaconda's installer includes the updated version of Numpy....would you suggest I just reinstall everything?

Comment: Anaconda can do updates. `conda update conda` `conda update anaconda` and `conda update numpy` will do it. I don't know if there is a GUI for Windows.